# Minimum number of nodes perfect binary tree

Tags: trees, binary, data-structure

definition of perfect binary is "which all internal nodes have two children and all leaves are at same level"

[perfect binary tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8l4X9.png)

i know max. node number:  2^h - 1  (h>=1)
but i cant figure out, what is minimum number of nodes perfect binary tree